# Let $ABC$ be an acute angled scalene triangle.

Tags: geometry, circles

Let $ABC$ be an acute angled scalene triangle. Let $P$ be a point on the extension of $AB$ past $B$, and $Q$ a point on the extension of $AC$ past $C$ such that $BPQC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. Let $N$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $A$ to $BC$. If $NP = NQ$ then prove that $N$ is also the centre of the circumcircle of $APQ$.

Comment: what is your try?

Comment: Where from does the problem come?

Comment: The circumcenter (O) of APQ would be that point such that it lies on the perpendicular bisector of PQ, and $∠OAP=90-∠PQA=90-∠B$. It is easy to see that N is this point.

Comment: @user184352: I agree with the statements in your first sentence. But I am not finding it easy to see that "$N$ is this point". Could you explain, please?

Answer (score 4):

Since $BCPQ$ is a cyclic quadrilateral, the $BC$-line is "[antiparallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiparallel_%28mathematics%29)" to the PQ-line. Since in a general triangle the orthocenter $H$ and the circumcenter $O$ are [isogonal conjugates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isogonal_conjugate), the $AN$-line goes through the orthocenter of $ABC$ and the circumcenter of $APQ$. Then, provided that $N$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$, $N\equiv O$ *is* the circumcenter of $APQ$.

[image]

Comment: @bentin in Jack's diagram $NP \ne NQ$; he chose it that way to make it easier to distinguish what one actually knows and what has to be proven. Moving the line $BNC$ towards $A$ makes the difference between $NP$ and $NQ$ even bigger.

Comment: I believe you got the diagram wrong instead of op = oq it is meant to be np=nq

Comment: @K.Bedekar: see coproc's comment. In the diagram $N$ is just the projection of $A$ on $BC$. I know that we are assuming $NP=NQ$; the diagram just shows the general situation without imposing $NP=NQ$. If we assume that, $N$ and the circumcenter $O$ of $ABC$ collapse.

Comment: I don't quite understand why just because n is a perpendicular bi sector of pq n is equal to o

Comment: @0327: a point cannot be a perpendicular bisector, anyway: $A,N,O$ are always collinear. $O$ always lies on the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$, hence if $NP=NQ$, $N\equiv O$, since both points are the intersection between the $AN$-line and the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$, and two lines cannot meet in more than one point.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote the angles of $\triangle ABC$ by $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$. Note that $BPQC$ being a cyclic quadrilateral is equivalent to $\angle AQP = \angle CBA = \beta$. With $O$ being the circumcenter of $\triangle APQ$ we have for the center angle above $PQ$
$$\angle POQ = 2 \angle PAQ = 2\alpha.$$ 
Hence in isosceles $\triangle OPQ$ we get
$$\angle OPQ = \angle OQP = (180 - 2\alpha)/2 = 90-\alpha.$$
Now we can compute
$$\angle AQO = \angle AQP - \angle OQP = \beta - (90 - \alpha) = 90 - \gamma.$$
In isosceles $\triangle AOQ$ we have
$$\angle OAQ = \angle AQO = 90 - \gamma,$$
which is the same as $\angle NAC$. Hence $N$ is on $OA$. Since $O$ and $N$ are both on the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$ and $\triangle APQ$ is scalene (as $\triangle ABC$ is), $O$ and $N$ must coincide. q.e.d.

Comment: There is a typo in line 8: $\alpha$ should be added, not subtracted. I follow your argument for the first ten lines. However, in line 11, I fail to see why $\angle NOC=90^{\circ}-\gamma$. Further, I don't see that $O$ and $N$ are both on the [perpendicular] bisector of $PQ$.

Comment: I fixed the calculation of $\angle AQO$ and the typo in $\angle NOC$ (I meant $\angle NAC$). Concerning the bisector of $PQ$: $OP=OQ$ because $O$ is the circumcenter of $\triangle APQ$ and $NP=NQ$ by the given statement.

Comment: @bentin sorry, my arguments towards the end are indeed a little scarce. But read them carefully again: only $O$ and $N$ are on the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$. If $O$ and $N$ are distinct, then - as you say - also $A$ would be on this bisector and $\triangle ABC$ would indeed not be scalene. So $O$ distinct from $N$ leads to a contradiction, hence $O=N$. (And $A$ is not on the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$.)

Comment: OK, thanks, I get it now. And I have deleted my incorrect answer and comments.

Comment: I don't quite understand why just because O and N are on the perpendicular bi sector of pq they must coincide. Could someone explain

Comment: @0327: why to give the bounty, then? Anyway, that happens because two lines (the $AN$-line and the erpendicular bisector of $PQ$) cannot meet in more than one point.

Answer (score 0):

Let us write $\angle CAB=\beta,\angle ACB=\gamma,$ and $\angle NPQ=\theta=\angle NQP$ (because triangle $PNQ$ is isosceles). Since $BPQC$ is cyclic, $\angle APQ=\angle ACB=\gamma$, and so $\angle NPA=\gamma-\theta$. Also, $\angle NAP=\angle NAB=\frac12\!\pi-\beta$ since $NA\perp NB$. Similarly, $\angle NQA=\beta-\theta$ and $\angle NAC= \frac12\!\pi-\gamma$. Applying the sine rule  to triangles $NPA$ and $NPQ$ gives $NP/NA=\sin(\frac12\!\pi-\beta)/\sin(\gamma-\theta)$ and $NQ/NA=\sin(\frac12\!\pi-\gamma)/\sin(\beta-\theta)$ respectively. These ratios are equal, and so $$\sin(\beta-\theta)\cos\beta=\sin(\gamma-\theta)\cos\gamma.$$This may be written $\sin(2\beta-\theta)-\sin\theta=\sin(2\gamma-\theta)-\sin\theta$ or$$\sin(2\beta-\theta)=\sin(2\gamma-\theta).$$Since $\beta\neq\gamma$, we have $$2\beta-\theta=\pi-(2\gamma-\theta),$$ or $\theta=\beta+\gamma-\frac12\!\pi$. Then $\angle NPA=\gamma-\theta=\frac12\!\pi-\beta=\angle NAP$. It follows that $NA=NP=NQ$, and hence $N$ is the circumcentre of triangle $APQ$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The red circle ($\pi$) circum-scribes APQ. Produce AN to cut ($\pi$) at G.

$\gamma = \delta$ .... [ext. angles cyclic quad.]

$= \epsilon$ .... [angles in the same segment]

This means, $BNGP$ is cyclic. This further means, $\alpha = \beta = 90^0$

Therefore, ANG is the diameter of $\pi \tag 1$

Let $H$ be the midpoint of $PC$ [**EDIT**:- $PQ$ instead]. Then, $\triangle NHP \cong\triangle NHQ$.

Therefore, $NH$ is the perpendicular bisector of the chord $PQ \tag 2$

$N$ is the intersection of (1) and (2) implies N is the center of $\pi$.

Comment: nice idea to use the cyclic $BNGP$. some details: you mean: $H$ is the midpoint of $PQ$? Note also that you have to use that $\triangle ABC$ is scalene to make your last implication work.

Comment: Nice catch. Fixed. Referring to the last part of your comment, please note that ABC was given as scalene. I checked that even if I assume A is obtuse, the proof still works except that figure will have to be drawn differently (example, P is then inside AB).

Comment: @coproc Pls see the previous comment.

Comment: Yes, $\triangle ABC$ is given as scalene, but you are not using that in your proof. For an isosceles triangle ($AB=AC$) the statement does not hold.

Comment: @coproc I guess what you have pointed out is just a particular case. If AB = AC, then $\angle ACB = \gamma = \delta = \alpha$. Suppose that line ANG cuts PQ at H’. Then, ANH’G is the perpendicular bisectors of BC and PQ. That is, H and H’ are the same point. The result still holds.

Comment: If $AB=AC$ then also $AP=AQ$ ($PQ$ must then be parallel to $BC$ to have $BCQP$ cyclic) and $N$ is on the bisector of $\angle BAC = \angle PAQ$. Hence $NP=NQ$ holds independent of the position of $P$ (and corresponding $Q$); $P$ and $Q$ can be anywhere on $AB$ and $AC$, resp., as long as $PQ$ is parallel to $BC$. But at only one position $N$ can be the circumcenter of $\triangle APQ$. Hence the statement does not hold in general for an isosceles $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: @coproc Agree that the given condition is necessary because otherwise there are infinitely many PQ pairs with only one N.